# Do I need to pay for all the cracked games/softwares I used in the past?

Tags: theft, human-rights

so in my teenage years I was playing games and downloading softwares illegally. I really didn't bother that time about what's halal and what's haram (may Allah forgive me). So after I found out that it is technically stealing, I stopped using them. But I am afraid that I'll have to buy all of these games and programs, what should I do?